# Json Decode Presentation With Category

Tags: php, json

I got these Json data:

```
[{"category":"Pizza","name":"Beef Pronto","desc":"Description of Beef Pronton here","price":"12"},
 {"category":"Drink","name":"Cool Delight","desc":"Description of Coold Delight here","price":"5"},
 {"category":"Drink","name":"Cola","desc":"Description of Cola","price":"4"}
 ]
```

With Javascript I have successfully managed data to present as follow:

**Pizza**

-Beef Pronto: Description of Beef Pronton here: 12

**Drink**

-Cool Delight: Description of Coold Delight here: 5

-Cola: Description of Cola: 4

> any Idea how to do it with **PHP** ?

**-->Ok guys, this is How I do it with PHP:**

```
<?
$listedmenuJSON = '[{"category":"Pizza","name":"Beef Pronto","desc":"Description of Beef Pronton here","price":"12"},
 {"category":"Drink","name":"Cool Delight","desc":"Description of Coold Delight here","price":"5"},
 {"category":"Drink","name":"Cola","desc":"Description of Cola","price":"4"}
 ]';

    $json_decoded = json_decode($listedmenuJSON);
    foreach ($json_decoded as $categoryvalue){
     //echo $categoryvalue->category."<br/>";
     $tempcategoryvalue[] = $categoryvalue->category;
     $arrunique = array_unique($tempcategoryvalue);
     }

    foreach ($arrunique as $tmpcategory){
    echo '<br/><b>'.$tmpcategory.'</b></br>';
     foreach ($json_decoded as $tempo){
      if($tempo->category == $tmpcategory){
       echo $tempo->name.'<br/>';
       echo '<i>'.$tempo->desc.'.......</i>';
       echo $tempo->price.'<br/>';
      }
     }

    }    
?>
```

It will generate as following:

**Pizza**
Beef Pronto
*Description of Beef Pronton here.......12*

**Drink**
Cool Delight
*Description of Coold Delight here.......5*
Cola
*Description of Cola.......4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got json in PHP Code Use Following line to convert json to PHP array and manipulate array for desire output

```
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

In javascript user below code to convert your json to array.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responce);
```

Comment: That's quite helpful...at least I know where to start now

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PHP function 'json_decode' (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This will create an associative array in PHP. It should be pretty simple to access and manipulate data thereon.

Comment: yes I'm close to it..but still trying to convert my Jscript logic to PHP which's not my strongest point

Answer (score 0):

If you use a SQL server then you can select form the table using "group by category"

Else, you can just verify many times the arrays.

SQL:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'table'
GROUP BY category
having (category=\"Pizza\");"


--SELECT * FROM 'table'
--GROUP BY category
--having (category="Drink");
```

if you use this in php you must use sql_query("query")